# Relative e/ou absolute path em PHP

Tags: php

Já fiz algumas buscas no StackOverflow sobre *absolute path* e *relative path*, mas nenhuma das soluções funcionou para o que preciso. Preciso que o `$host` (exemplo abaixo) aponte para onde está o meu `index.php` dinamicamente, ou seja, se mudar a hospedagem não preciso alterar manualmente o endereço. Alguma sugestão?

```
$host."index.php?id=2&url=".$link."&title=".$noticia."&s=1&logo=".$foto;

$host = "http://exemplo.com.br/teste/"
```

Comment: $host = ("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); isso vai retornar h ttp://exemplo.com.br

Comment: No HTML, quando colocar uma barra `/` a frente do arquivo, você estará indicando que o caminho é relativo ao diretório raiz do servidor. Ao fazer `/index.php`, isso sempre apontará parao `index.php` da raiz da aplicação, independente de qual domínio seja. Isso resolveria seu problema? Qual à sua segunda pergunta, a removerei por tornar a pergunta ampla demais, mas se precisar pode abrir uma nova pergunta sobre o assunto. Já adianto e pesquise sobre a classe nativa `DOMDocument` que provavelmente lhe será útil.

Comment: Eu já tinha tentado essa duas alternativas, mas comigo não funcionou.